# Is it possible to retract an edit reject?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I usually do pay attention when reviewing edits, but in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25509808) I made a stupid mistake. It appeared to me that the edit (not made by OP) added code and text that was not present in the original post.

I could have paid more attention, no doubt. However, we all make mistakes sometimes, so is it possible to retract a vote to reject an edit?

Comment: No, a decision in a queue can't be retracted, but you can perform actions on the question itself, like applying the edit yourself if it got rejected (or revert the edit if it got approved), retract close votes and flags there or undo an up- or down vote.